# What's wrong with this Clojure function?

Tags: clojure

I'am new to clojure and i wrote this func:

```
 (def fact (fn [n] (
   (apply * (drop 1 (range n))))))
```

When calling it i get the error:

> ClassCastException class java.lang.Long cannot be cast to class clojure.lang.IFn (java.lang.Long is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; clojure.lang.IFn is in unnamed module of loader 'app')  my-stuff.core/fact (form-init3352210926102455316.clj:18)

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got an extra parenthesis around apply:

```
(def fact (fn [n]
              (apply * (drop 1 (range n)))))
```

Comment: Wow thanks i will delete my question now

Answer (score 1):

There's extra pair of parentheses- when you call for example `(fact 3)`, result will be `(2)` (not list, but call of function) and `2` isn't function, so it throws error.

When you remove these parentheses, like this:

```
(def fact (fn [n]
    (apply * (drop 1 (range n)))))
```

, call `(fact 3)` returns `2`- but is this result correct? If you want to return factorial for given number, you have to use [`range`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/range) correctly:

```
(defn fact [n]
  (->> (range 1 (inc n))
       (apply *)))
```

([`->>`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/-%3E%3E) is thread-last macro)

Example:

```
(fact 3)
=> 6
```

Comment: Thanks, very illuminating